# Multiple templates for TabPanel control in DevExtreme Angular

Tags: angular, tabpanel, devextreme

I'm developing web project on DevExtreme (Angular "version") library. I have stuck with TabPanel control. There is example [demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Tab_Panel/Overview/jQuery/Light/) on developers site. But this demo uses one template for every panel.I need to use two-three different templates. For example, first tab contains datagrid, second tab contains charts and etc.
Can anyone help me with that trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create desired template in view like

```
<div *dxTemplate="let company of 'tab1Template'">
   <div class="tabpanel-item">
      Tab1 custom template
   </div>
</div>
```

where `tab1Template` is the name of your custom template
Then specify this template for your item by using `template` property

```
companies = [{
  "ID": 1,
  "CompanyName": "SuprMart",
  ...
  template: 'tab1Template' // this line
},
...
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WnNppS2x95CzwGABd8E1?p=preview)**